# Meteor.call() with return value while server have async work

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I'm working with Meteor and I'm trying to retrieve data from an external database (neo4j for that case).

My problem is when I `Meteor.call()` from the client to the server I need to have a `return` statement in the server function. But retrieving data from the database is async by itself.

This is a snippest of what I have:

client.js:

```
Template.test.created = function () {
    Meteor.call('getData', id, function (error, response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log(response); //<-- reponse = "???"
        }
    });
}
```

server.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    "getData": function (id) {
        neo.commit ( //<-- async function which expect a callback
            id,
            function(error, response) {
                console.log(response); //<-- only here I have the response I want but now I cant "return" it.
                return response;
            }
        );
        return "???"; //<-- the actual return that is being send back
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Future` to fix your problem, Change your code to(it may need more changes depending on your code base):

```
...

var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
    "getData": function (id) {
        var future = new Future();
        neo.commit ( //<-- async function which expect a callback
            id,
            function(error, response) {
                if (error) return future.throw(error);
                return future.return(response);
            }
        );
        return future.wait();
    }
});
```

You can read more about Meteor's async patterns in the following links:

[Async On Meteor Server](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Async_on_server)

[Meteor Async Guide](https://gist.github.com/joscha/4130605)

[Meteor Patterns: Call an asynchronous function and use its returned value](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399)

Feel free to ask if you need further helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm (: